# How to use boolean conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm obviously confused with boolean flow because I run into a problem each time. NOTE: I am teaching myself to program, you are all my only hope in learning! I am trying to define a method that checks if a user is an admin, so that I can display certain objects in views to ONLY admins simple enough...or not, for some reason it's not recognizing that I'm an admin (when I truly am, I've checked!). With this all being said, I am a newb so go easy on me!

`helpers/sessions_helper` is used by both my User and Blogpost models:

```
def current_user #determines if user is logged out or is the current user of the session/cookie of profile
  if (user_id = session[:user_id])
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
  elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
    user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
    if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
      log_in user
      @current_user = user
    end
  end
end

def current_user?(user)
  user == current_user
end

def is_an_admin
  if current_user && current_user.admin?
  end
end 

<div class="col-xs-12">
  <h1><%= @blogpost.title %></h1>
  <p><%= @blogpost.content %></p>
  <% if is_an_admin %>
    <%= link_to "Return to blog", blogposts_path %>
    <%= link_to "Edit Post", edit_blogpost_path, class: 'btn btn-primary' %> | 
    <%= link_to "Delete Post", blogpost_path(@blogpost), 
                method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: 'btn btn-danger' %>    
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to "Return to blog", blogposts_path %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I'm unsure if maybe I have the method in the wrong place? I have tried placing it inside my applications controller and my user controller to no avail. I must be missing something.

Comment: Writing your own login and authentication system is not easy, so you might want to use a canned solution like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) if you're just getting started. Note that your `is_an_admin` method doesn't return anything, ever, it just does a test that branches into an empty block of code. You probably mean to have the body of the `if` condition left there, in isolation, which will mean that method actually returns the result of evaluating that.

Comment: @tadman I am seeing this, but if I struggle now itll be easier when I take the road with a good breeze. I have learned a large amount, and users can indeed sign in and out now with saved sessions (which is pretty cool, took me forever but it's cool!)

Comment: I'm glad you got that far, but it can be a struggle to do it properly, securely, and in a way that keeps pace with external pressures. Devise is actually pretty simple, and even more importantly, you can easily add in support for things like OAuth so people can log in with Twitter, Facebook or Google if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sintax got messed up, but I think you're always returning nil on the is_an_admin method:

```
def is_an_admin
  if current_user && current_user.admin?
  end
end
```

It does nothing if the condition is true so it's always returning nil

Change it to something like:

```
def is_an_admin?
  current_user and current_user.admin? # or shorter: current_user.try('admin?')
end
```

Comment: In Ruby 2.4+ you can also do `current_user&.admin?` to use the safe-navigation operator.

Comment: Okay so how is and vs && any different? also I've read up on try and used it in my views until I decided it was too clumsy to continuously rewrite when I could simply make a method such as I have. It appears I was close but sadly close isn't good enough. @tadman what is a safe-navigator?

Comment: @ColtonVanBastelaere on that case, they work the same way so I like to use the more readable "and" than "&&", check stackoverflow, there are differences but it's far better explained on specific questions and google http://www.virtuouscode.com/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/

Comment: Thank you very much, @arieljuod I agree it is easier to read (especially for me) thank you for the help, I also noticed that there was an "if" in my method statement that was not suppose to be there...dnno why or how it got there, hopefully this helps others who might read this!

Comment: The "safe-navigation operator" is described in [posts like this](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) which go into more detail than I can here.